# Symfony event subscriber not working even service is defined

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an event subscriber:

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\Token;
use App\Model\EncryptUtils;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;

class DatabaseSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'prePersist'
        );
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        if ($entity instanceof Token) {
            $enityt->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        }
    }
}
```

And I've declared the service in services.yaml:
    parameters:
        locale: 'en'

```
services:

    App\EventListener\DatabaseSubscriber:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }

    _defaults:
        autowire: true      
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false       

        bind:
            $appSecret: '%kernel.secret%'

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

But there's no way to get it working. I've also tried with an event listener but nothing happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare your service after all the default configuration because if not, the default configuration is overriding yours.
So your services.yaml file should be:

```
services:

    _defaults:
        autowire: true      
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false       

        bind:
            $appSecret: '%kernel.secret%'

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    App\EventListener\DatabaseSubscriber:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```